# Error while creating a backbone.js view - Expecting a function in instanceof check, but got [object Object]

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views

I am trying to create a simple backbone.js view with the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.3.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js"></script>
        <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script> -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var BodyView = Backbone.View.extend({
                el:$('body'),
                initialize : function() {
                    console.log("view init");
                }
            });

            new BodyView();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But

> I am getting an error Expecting a function in instanceof check, but
>   got [object Object]

on this line - `new BodyView()`;

This code is working if i use an older version of backbone.js(0.3.3)

Any idea why this error is happening and how to solve it?.Thanks in advance.

P.S - I have been mainly following http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-view/ and http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View for creating this sample backbone js app.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Basic things you should check out :

#### Wrap your `new BodyView()` in jQuery.ready like this :

```
 var BodyView = Backbone.View.extend({
     el:$('body'),
     initialize : function() {
         console.log("view init");
     }
 });

 $(function() {
        new BodyView();
 });
```

#### Load jQuery before Underscore and Backbone

Your script line for jquery should be before that of Backbone.

Your code actually works : http://jsfiddle.net/vTuPJ/

Comment: answered 4 mins ago - drinchev, answered 5 mins ago - fguillen. it took me 1 minute for the jsfiddle :P

Comment: Thanks.That did the trick.But any idea why jquery has to be loaded before backbone.Have not seen this point anywhere in the backbone.js website afaik..

Comment: Yep, because of [this line](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L42) in the source which loads jQuery in Backbone :

Comment: 'Load jQuery before Underscore and Backbone' answered everything

Comment: I see something that shouldn't work, in my mind.  The initialization of the "el" property to $('body') would seem to need the DOM loaded; isn't that initialization evaluated even before the var BodyView assignment?  Before even getting to new BodyView()?

Comment: Never mind, I see it wrapped in the body tag.  It does introduce a dependency I think, so that if this code is ever in a separate JS file, there will be restrictions on where its script tag can be.  This could cause the same kind of confusion later on.

Answer (score 6):

Works for me. Try to wrapper all the Backbone code in a `documentReady` block:

```
$(function(){
  // .. your backbone code
});​
```

Another thing is that maybe you have to change the order of the scripts loads:

1. underscore
2. jquery
3. backbone